# Return type with typeclass but no other type info

Tags: scala, functional-programming, typeclass, scala-cats

Lets say I have some typeclass:

```
trait Greeter[A] {
  def greet(a: A): String
}
```

And I want to write a method that returns values for which an instance of this typeclass exists:

```
implicit val intGreeter = new Greeter[Int] {
  def greet(n: Int): String = s"Hello, integer $n!"
}

implicit val doubleGreeter = new Greeter[Double] {
  def greet(d: Double): String = s"Hello, double $d"
}

def foo(b: Boolean): <X> = {
  if (b) 3 else 1.0
}
```

Where `<X>` is some type signature. And then use it something like:

```
val g: <X> = foo(true)
println(implicitly[Greeter[<X>]].greet(g))
```

Of course this doesn't work directly. I could do something like this:

```
trait Greetable {
  def greet: String
}

def getGreetable[A : Greeter](a: A) = new Greetable {
  def greet: String = implicitly[Greeter[A]].greet(a)
}

def foo(b: Boolean): Greetable = {
  if (b) getGreetable(3) else getGreetable(1.0)
}
```

This works just fine, but it seems a bit inconvenient and not really extensible. I have to define a corresponding trait for every typeclass. And what if I want a return type that has instances for *two* typeclasses? Or n? This also feels like a very OO approach; is there something from the FP world that addresses this?

Comment: I'd be surprised if this is possible, because the return type of the method would be dependent on which implicits are currently in scope. This strikes me as something that would cause problems for the type system in general, and for the compiler in particular as I'd expect implicit resolution to happen after method signature typing has completed. Sadly, I can't find anything solid supporting that intuition.

Comment: @Joe K any luck with this one?

Answer (score 1):

As long as your method really needs to return 3 or 1.0 depending on some condition, and that part cannot be changed, then you surely need a sum type for the return type.

This can be modeled either via a common superclass, which is the approach you took, or via disjoint unions such as `Either`, `scalaz.\/` etc., in which case you would return e.g. `Int \/ Double`. If there are many potential types that could come out, then you would need an "either of an either of an either" or a (much more convenient) [shapeless HList](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#heterogenous-lists), or simply stick to the superclass `Greetable`.

I think that the clunkiness of this situation stems not from the solution, but from the problem itself. Method which returns two or more different types based on some internal logic is not really FP itself, is it? :)